# Having problem setting parameters for LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

```
my %parameters = (
                        key => 'value'
                 );
my $response = $ua->get('http://example.com/i', %parameters);
```

I'm trying to get content of `http://example.com/i?key=value`,but after debugging I found the `%parameters` are stored in http headers instead of url parameters.

What's wrong in my code?

Though perldoc tells me that :

```
$ua->get( $url , $field_name => $value, ... )
```

But it should also work if I put those parameters in a `%parameters`,right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The additional parameters to `get` are HTTP headers. For GET requests, arguments are included in the URL itself, URLencoded. You can use the [URI](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/URI/URI.pm) module to create the appropriate URLs including GET variables, or construct them yourself (probably using URI::Escape to urlencode the values).

e.g.:

```
my %parameters = (
                        key => 'value'
                 );
my $url = URI->new("http://example.com/i");
$url->query_form(%parameters);
my $response = $ua->get($url);
```

Comment: `%parameters` should be an array. You can repeat parameters in a URL. `@parameters = ('a[]'=>42, 'a[]'=43)` is a valid set of fields.

Answer (score 3):

From the [fine manual](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#REQUEST_METHODS):

> $ua->get( $url )
>   $ua->get( $url , $field_name => $value, ... )
>   This method will dispatch a GET request on the given $url. **Further arguments can be given to initialize the headers of the request.**

Emphasis mine. You're misreading the documentation, the extra parameters for `get()` are HTTP header fields, not CGI parameters. If you want to include some CGI parameters then you'll have to add them to the URI yourself (preferably with [URI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/)).